# How do I find these particular elements in a webpage, with selenium using chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a website that I'm trying to automate but I can't find a particular link with selenium to click on.  It *looks* like a link on the website, but when I use the chrome "inspect" function, it looks like it might be a button (???).   I've tried copying the Xpath, but that doesn't work.

Here is the HTML behind the link

```
<button ng-bind-html="::ListingCtrl.copy.planListing.noPreference" track="No Preference" ng-click="::ListingCtrl.enterNoPreference()" class="link ally-focus-within">No Preference</button>
```

The Xpath for it is

```
//*[@id="mainContent"]/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/h2/button
```

The text of the link is "No Preference", so also tried the following

```
elem_NoPreference = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//@track=\'No Preference\'')
```

But I'm not sure if my quote escape characters are correct.

I also unsuccessfully tried the following

```
elem_NoPreference = browser.find_element_by_link_text('No Preference') <br>
elem_NoPreference = browser.find_element_by_class_name('link ally-focus-within') <br>
elem_NoPreference = browser .find_element_by_css_selector("button[class='link ally-focus-within']
```

I should mention that the following are unique in the HTML.  So, if there is a way to find these using the Xpath, it would be helpful

```
ListingCtrl.copy.planListing.noPreference 
ListingCtrl.enterNoPreference()
track = "No Preference"
```

I'm at my wits end here.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't plan to do any [I18N / L10N](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) testing you can stick to `No Preference` text, in this case the selector would be:

```
//button[text()='No Preference']
```

[image]

other option is basically the same, but instead of text it looks for `track` [HTML attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp):

[image]

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=40044727)
- [Xpath cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/xpath)

Comment: Wow.  You're fast.  Thank you.  In the meantime, since I posted the question, I found the xpath helper wizard extension for chrome and used it to test your suggestion.  Both worked perfectly by selecting the No Preference element.  But now when I immediately follow that code with elem_NoPreference.click(), nothing happens.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Try with this xpath:

```
elem_NoPreference = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@track='No Preference']")
```

or, if you want to select the element by the containing text:

```
elem_NoPreference = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(.,'No Preference')]")
```